# Movie where a key can open any door by imagining where you want to go to

Tags: story-identification, movie, magic

A movie where there’s a key which fits any door. It works by, you think of a place and open a door, the door opens for the place you imagined.
For example, you think of a bar and open a door, the door you open happens to be a door in that bar you thought of.

In the ending of the movie a villain keeps the protagonist's daughter at a place he imagined and tries to negotiate something with the protagonists. But the protagonist kills him and ends up on not finding his daughter.

I think it’s his daughter, that’s how I remember.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could it be **[The Lost Room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Room)**? It's a 2006 science fiction television miniseries that aired on the Sci Fi Channel in the United States:

> Detective Joe Miller comes into possession of a seemingly innocuous motel room key while working on a murder case. The key can open every door and take him into a motel room that seems to exist outside of normal time and space. However, if he leaves something in the motel room that did not originally come from there, it will be gone as soon as the room "resets"... He discovers that there are special objects hidden in different places. They don't look special, but they have special powers. When his daughter disappears and he is framed for killing his partner, he must find a way to bring her back from the room, while working with different groups and people searching for the objects. But who can he really trust when everyone goes crazy after touching the objects ? ...

(I've never seen it, but it fits your description)

Comment: Thank God. Thank you for the answer and yes that is it,